# hibernate creates one to many relationship in mysql db, while one to one specified

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

After defining @OneToOne relationship using Hibernate, I have one to many relationship in MySQL db.

one to many relationship:

[image: one to many relationship]

Is it an errror or the way Hibernate manages one to one relationship?

I have even tried this with obvious example from site explaining relationships: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-hibernate-associations

Code:

```java
    @Entity
    public class Employee {
     
        @Id
        private Long id;
     
        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "parking_spot_id")
        private ParkingSpot parkingSpot;
     
    }
    
    @Entity
    public class ParkingSpot {
     
        @Id
        private Long id;
     
    }
```

Comment: one-to-one and ano-to-many relationships are conceptually different, hibernate does not do that, the many-to-many relationship is defined using two one-to-many relationships only, so please make sure you delete the existing database(if it is possible) and then run code to create tables again, and if you can please provide some more code parts of your project like configurations , etc

Comment: I have deleted & executed code few times (deleting db tables in the meantime), using different configurations, and all of them created one to many relationship in MySQL db structure (examples from one-to-one tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-one-to-one). So does it mean that Hibernate is unable to create actual one to one relationship?

Answer (score 0):

The relationship in your MySQL database doesn't depend on Hibernate relationship definition. Hibernate annotation @OneToOne is used to specify particular relationship for your program - due to that Hibernate will expect one-to-one relationship for accordance tables, already existing in your database. If you want to get one-to-one relationship in database, just drop old tables with one-to-many relationship and create new with one-to-one (use this tutorial - https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/database-relationships-in-mysql/) - you don't need Hibernate for this.

Comment: I know that it is possible in MySQL, I just wanted to define whole db with Hibernate. So does it mean that i can't define one-to-one relationship, that will be set this way in MySQL, with just hibernate?

Comment: Yes, it does mean this